# RVM hangs on 'Installing required packages' on Debian

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I installed rvm on debian 7 using the command:

`\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails`

from this article:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-an-debian-7-0-wheezy-vps-using-rvm

I get this output:

`Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file https://rvm.io/binaries/debian/7/x86_64/ruby-2.1.0.tar.bz2
Checking requirements for debian.
Installing requirements for debian.
Updating system...
Installing required packages: gawk, g++, libreadline6-dev, zlib1g-dev, libssl-dev, libyaml-dev, libsqlite3-dev, sqlite3, autoconf, libgdbm-dev, libncurses5-dev, automake, libtool, bison, pkg-config, libffi-dev`

It hangs here forever. I tried waiting about 30 min.  I also tried hitting ctrl-c and running some rvm commands.  `rvm list known` works fine, but rvm install gets me back to the same "installing requirements" and it hangs as well.

Any ideas?  Googleing only seemed to bring up issues involving OSX (I'm using debian in a vbox in windows 8).

Would installing each required package indiviually via `apt-get` be the best move?

Comment: Oh and I also tried running: rvm requirements. Same result.

Comment: Maybe try installing those requirements by hand? Maybe something silently fails?

Comment: Meh... I'll give that a try, was hoping they're would be a easier solution.  Gawk is asking me for a disk or something. Thanks tho

Comment: Aw yea. That was it. Thanks dude.

Comment: So i'll write this as answer, have you found what was blocking the installation?

Comment: Yea it was the gawk package. apt-get gawk wants you to put in a disk for some reason.  I installed gawk via this question:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/244268/installing-gawk-4-0-on-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: And specifically the manual installation using dpkg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i've written in comment, try installing requirements by hand, sometimes something wilk silently fail and cause such issues. As OP found, the gawk package was causing the issue.

Comment: Should add this to the answer:  download from here http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gawk/gawk_4.0.1+dfsg-2_amd64.deb  and run command sudo dpkg -i gawk_4.0.1+dfsg-2_amd64.deb

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue. To resolve, just mount the installation CD that you used to install Debian and it will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, sorted it for me.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same issue with Debian 8. As it turns out, the installation was looking for the required packages on the Debian install CD-ROM, which wasn't inserted. To fix this, run the following command:

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then, comment out the line beginning with "cdrom" so that it looks like the following:

```
# cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux...
```

You should be able to run sudo apt-get update then try installing rvm again. However, I restarted my laptop before doing so. Therefore, I can't give 100% confirmation that it works without restarting.

Comment: I had had the same problem with `curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`, so I've inserted the Debian install CD-ROM and the installation has completed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the cdrom entry from the sources.list file. This can be done easily:

```
sudo sed -i '/cdrom/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

This should take care of the problem. The message is because somehow you still have the cdrom entry in your sources.list file, you can check the content of the file using: